# How to implement security Authorization using scala and play?

Tags: scala, security, authentication

I am using scala and play framework. I want to use play security Authorization in my app.

Previously I implemented it in project using java and play like following :

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {
    private static String EMAIL = "Email";
  private static String U_COOKIE = "ucookie";
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        String decodedText = null;
        String CHARSET = "ISO-8859-1";
        Cookies cookies = play.mvc.Controller.request().cookies();
        try {
            Cookie emailCookie = cookies.get(EMAIL);
      Cookie uCookie = cookies.get(U_COOKIE);
      if (uCookie !=null && uCookie.value() != null) {
    String userId = uCookie.value();
      }
            if (emailCookie != null && emailCookie.value() != null) {
                String email = emailCookie.value();
                try {
                    decodedText = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(email.getBytes(CHARSET)));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return decodedText;
    }

    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        String done = play.mvc.Controller.request().path();
        return redirect(routes.RegController.signIn(done));
    }
}
```

and I used above Authorization in all of my method using

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
```

Before any of my methods throughout my application.

When I call any method @before that method gives call to secured class and authenticate user.

Now I want to implement same thing using scala. Following are my questions....

1) Is it possible to use @ to inherit and call methods of secured class??

2) What is the right method to call play's security authentication??

P.S. I want to use cookies for implementation of security Authentication/Authorization.

Any help or workaround will be great favor..

Answer (score 10):

If you build an application intended for production:
**Don't do it**

Use one of the many frameworks out there:

- Deadbolt2 : https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2
- SecureSocial: http://www.securesocial.ws/
- Silhouette : http://silhouette.mohiva.com/

They are also a great starting point to look for best practices.

If you want to do it mainly for learning and there are no real scecurity concerns go for:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition

There look for the heading **auth** it gives some information how to do it.

To have the authentication kick in before any method you could use a **Filter** to intercept the request:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaInterceptors

Comment: Which of the mentioned frameworks is your favorite and why? What would you recommend to implement a simple authentication?

Comment: At the moment there seem to be some compatibility problems with the latest Play versions.

Comment: No preference so far. Deadbolt seems to be the one to go for as it might even become part of play.

Comment: In my case it would be extremely easy to do it by hand, since I only need a User table with email and password. Why should I not do it by hand? Are you sure that Deadbolt2 is so popular. The last commit was 2 years ago.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Modules these are the officially supported modules. Deadbolt is part of the list.

Comment: Why should you not do it by hand: There are many possible errors that can creep in, if you you have not much experience in that area there is always a danger of missing something important. See not reinvent the wheel

Comment: Here's a reason to do it by hand: maintainability. Deadbolt and SecureSocial haven't been updated in a year. I happen to have an application that I can not update to the latest play/slick because, since SecureSocial plugin does not support the latest play version, I would have to rewrite the authorization layer. The libraries are not mature so choosing one is gambling on what will be "the one" 3 years from now.